# Rails multiple routes to same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I submitted my sitemap to google as example.com/sitemap where example.com is my domain Watching my server access log requests come in for sitemap.txt and sitemap.xml Can I just add routes for sitemap.txt and sitemap.xml for a total of 3 routes to the same controller action? I thought of "redirect" but I don't think it applies

What should I do with requests for sitemap.xml and sitemap.txt when I'm already serving requests to /sitemap

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything. Rails will automatically handle extensions.

Lets say you have one of these routes:

```
# Both of these options generate the same routes
get :sitemap, to: 'sitemaps#show'
resource :sitemap, only: :show
```

If you run `rails routes -c sitemap` you can see that it matches the pattern `/sitemap(.:format)`.

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
sitemap GET  /sitemap(.:format) sitemaps#show
```

To respond to various formats you can either just create views for each format and use [implicit rendering](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ImplicitRender.html) if what you're doing is very simple:

```
class SitemapsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /sitemaps.txt
  # GET /sitemaps.xml
  def show
    # this is optional but it can be good to enumerate which formats 
    # you should actually accept
    respond_to :txt, :xml
  end
end
```

This will render `app/views/sitemaps/show.#{format}.html.erb`.

Or you can use [MimeResponds](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) to handle each type explicitly:

```
class SitemapsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /sitemaps.txt
  # GET /sitemaps.xml
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.txt { ... }
      format.xml { ... }
    end
  end
end
```

This can be a good idea if you're for example generating the XML without a view. Or you can even do a mix by omitting the block.

Comment: I'm generating xml to the view index.xml.builder

Comment: @Cindy I honestly haven't used builder for anything but the most rudimentary but if its registered as a template engine then Rails should automatically find the corresponding view. On a side note its pretty wild that Rails depends on a gem that hasn't been updated since it's creator and only maintainer passed away a decade ago.

Answer (score -2):

yes you definitely can easily route to the same action, the file suffix (.xml, .txt, .html etc) is defined as a parameter in your routes file. So for example you might define a route like this:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
get 'sitemap(.:format)', to 'sitemap.index'
```

In your SitemapController, the index method would receive a params hash that includes the :format key, with a value of 'xml', 'txt', 'html'. Does that meet your needs?

Comment: You don't need this.  `get :sitemap, to: 'sitemap#index'`  will match the exact same pattern.